# axios breaks when 4xx returns

Tags: reactjs, axios, create-react-app

before anything I am using the following packages with creat-react-app

```
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"react-router": "^5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.4"
```

and I use the **Axios** simply like this

```
const submit = () => {
  Axios({
    method: "post",
    url: validUrl, // url is valid
    data: eitherValidOrNotValidData
  })
    .then((resp) => { console.log(resp) })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
    .finally(() => { })
}
```

this function created to use Axios in a react function and submit is set to a button click handler

when I click the related button the following error will be raise

```
POST http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

or

```
POST http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/ 401 (Unauthorized)
```

or anything else

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error is not a constructor
  at createError (createError.js:17)
  at settle (settle.js:19)
  at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

and this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'undefined' in instanceof check
  at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
```

the big problem is that when Axios calls with `method: "get"` it works correctly but when using `method: "post"` it should run catch an log the error but Axios will raise the above errors. but I need to see errors are responded from the server.

another important thing is that these errors occur just in development mode. it means when I run it with `npm start` or `yarn start`. so to test the APIs I should build the app and then serve the built version to see the functionallity of apis. but I want to see them in development.

and funny thing is that the error status code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but maybe it would be helpful to rewrite your request like so. That object format seems to be messy to me.

```
const submit = () => {
  Axios
    .post(validUrl, data)
    .then((resp) => { console.log(resp) })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
    .finally(() => { });
};
```